# Laravel MySQL Query not working error (Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 264245248 bytes)

Tags: laravel

Any idea why this query will not work in Laravel 7? It runs fine in MySQL workbench. Error reported is Memory error

```
$rows = Sections::select("t1.name AS lev1, t1.id as lev1_id, t2.name as lev2, t2.id as lev2_id, t3.name as lev3, t3.id as lev3_id, t4.name as lev4, t4.id as lev4_id, t5.name as lev5, t5.id as lev5_id
        sections AS t1
        LEFT JOIN sections AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.id
        LEFT JOIN sections AS t3 ON t3.parent = t2.id
        LEFT JOIN sections AS t4 ON t4.parent = t3.id
        LEFT JOIN sections AS t5 ON t5.parent = t4.id
        WHERE t1.name = 'Windows'");
```

Comment: This code wouldn't *do* anything - it builds a query. Show us where the query gets *executed*, via something like a `get()` call. Chances are you need to use `chunk()` if it's a large data set. I also don't think `select()` is going to work the way you think it does here.

Comment: Thing is, there is only 4 records in the table. It errors when I try to do a print_r($rows). I have changed the query to

Answer (score -1):

Your server as exceed the maximum memory limit of 536MB and trying to allocate more 264MB. You need to increase your memory limit on your php.ini file or reduce your dataset.

Answer (score -1):

copy your script first line and try it

`ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');`

Answer (score -1):

I have changed the query to

$rows = Sections::selectRaw('t1.name AS lev1, t1.id as lev1_id, t2.name as lev2, t2.id as lev2_id, t3.name as lev3, t3.id as lev3_id, t4.name as lev4, t4.id as lev4_id, t5.name as lev5, t5.id as lev5_id
        sections AS t1
        JOIN sections AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.id
        JOIN sections AS t3 ON t3.parent = t2.id
        JOIN sections AS t4 ON t4.parent = t3.id
        JOIN sections AS t5 ON t5.parent = t4.id
        WHERE t1.name = ?', ['Windows'])
                ->get()

now the error is

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'sections AS t1 JOIN sections AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.id JOIN sec' at line 2 (SQL: select t1.name AS lev1, t1.id as lev1_id, t2.name as lev2, t2.id as lev2_id, t3.name as lev3, t3.id as lev3_id, t4.name as lev4, t4.id as lev4_id, t5.name as lev5, t5.id as lev5_id sections AS t1 JOIN sections AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.id JOIN sections AS t3 ON t3.parent = t2.id JOIN sections AS t4 ON t4.parent = t3.id JOIN sections AS t5 ON t5.parent = t4.id WHERE t1.name = Windows from `sections`)